# Unable to see attributes in abstract methods that are overridden

Tags: delphi, attributes

I have an abstract class from which I derive a concrete class by overriding the abstract methods. I have discovered that any attributes I put on the overridden methods are not visible. After looking at the Delphi docs I find this sentence: "Note that the declared attribute class must not be declared as class abstract and should not contain any abstract methods." My question is, does anyone know of any way to make such attributes visible?

Comment: After rereading the documentation, I thin the sentence I quote above now refers to the actual attribute class itself. However, I still can't see the attributes on my derived class.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem which is worth sharing. The attribute class I defined was called TAPIHelpAttribute.The attribute I actually used to decorate the methods was called TAPIHelpAttrribute. Note the extra 'r' in the name. The compiler didn't pick up on the fact that I'd made a spelling error.

Comment: Good catch -- note that the compiler will ignore attributes it doesn't recognize, as a quirk of the vestiges of Delphi for .Net

Comment: You should read the compiler messages. It would have told you: W1025 Unsupported language feature: 'custom attribute'